# In Act 1 Chapter 2 of Bulletstorm, on the train, where can I find cover?

Tags: bulletstorm

"Last Train from Explosion Town"

I'm up to the point where the flying enemies start coming at you, and I just get cut down every time. I can't find somewhere to cover during this sequence and I've tried it half a dozen times at least. Is there a good strategy I should be aware of?

I'm playing on Xbox360 - don't know if that really makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this on the PC on hard, but it should remain fairly similar.

Using the minigun make sure you blow up any explosives on the train(s) that follow you to take out the various shooters. One has a boss on the left side, take him down quickly with focused fire from the minigun. This should give you some more breathing room when you take on the flyers. The flyers are easiest taken down by leashing, and hitting the right spot in the reaction timer that follows after you leash them. Then quickly proceed to the next until they are all dead.

There's no real cover to speak of and the best way I found was in using speed to get the enemies down to a manageable size.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to a walkthrough that I watched on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEMWPWCbPKs) you are supposed to pull the flying enemies down with your energy leash.

Answer (score 0):

Stand at the end of the train closest to the Badguy train. This will kill the enemies the fastest and you should be able to kill the enemy train baddies before the choppers come. If you do need cover try crouching behind the end of small walls on the sides, it's not very good, but can buy you some time if need be.